# how to make system service out of .jar file? (linux)

Tags: java, centos

i wrote a little java server which i'm running on my CentOS 5 VPS server. currently i just ssh onto the server and start the jar through commandline.
How an i turn this jar into a system service and set it such that it starts automatically when the system starts and also that it restarts automatically if it crashes?

Answer (score 2):

Common solution is to use [JSW](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp), I think

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html) from the Apache Commons project. You'll still need to write an init script utilizing `jsvc`, though.